# How do I refer to a footnote with supertabular?

Tags: footnotes, supertabular

I use the mpsupertabular environment of supertabular in order to permit footnote. The basic \footnote command works fine, although it uses letters rather than numbers for the footnote marks. However, when I attempt to refer to a previous footnot the footnote mark render as a number, rather than the letter of the original footnote. I tried using \footnotemark[\alph{fn:sub}], but that gives me the error message

! Missing number, treated as zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\begin{document}

\section {Symbols}
\label{sec:Symbols}
These macros simply generated predefined symbols in an appropriate font. Change them as appropriate for your house
style.

\bottomcaption{Symbols}
\tablefirsthead%
{
  \hline
  Macro & Definition & Meaning \\
  \hline
%  & & \\
%  \hline
}

\tablehead%
{
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\small\sl continued from previous page} \\
  \hline
  Macro & Definition & Meaning \\
  \hline
%  & & \\
%  \hline
}

\tabletail%
{
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\small\sl continued on next page} \\
  \hline
}

\tablelasttail%
{
  \hline
}

\begin{mpsupertabular}[t]{| l | l | p{3.2in} |}
A & B &  C
\footnote{footnote.}
\newcounter{fn:sub}
\setcounter{fn:sub} {\value{mpfootnote}}
\\
\hline
D & E & F
({\textbackslash}alph\{fn:sub\} = \alph{fn:sub})
\footnotemark[\value{fn:sub}]
\\
%    \hline
%    D & E & F
%    ({\textbackslash}alph\{fn:sub\} = \alph{fn:sub})
%    \footnotemark[\alph{fn:sub}]
%    Gets ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\omscmr.fd")
%    ! Missing number, treated as zero.
%    \\
\end{mpsupertabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment `mpsupertabular` puts a table page into a `minipage`, therefore the footnote markers of `\footnote` come from the `\footnote` inside a `minipage` with markers as small letters by default.

`\footnotemark` is not intended for the footnotes of the `minipage`, but for the footnotes of the page. Therefore, it is numbered as the page footnotes. `\footnotetext` would then go outside the `minipage`.

The following example defines `\mpfootnotemark` in a similar way as `\footnotemark`, but applied to the `minipage` footnotes. Then, `\mpfootnotemark[\value{fn:sub}]` uses the markers formatted for `minipage` footnotes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mpfootnotemark}{%
  \@ifnextchar[\@xmpfootnotemark{%
    \stepcounter{mpfootnote}%
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfootnote}%
    \@footnotemark
  }%
}
\def\@xmpfootnotemark[#1]{%
  \begingroup
    \c@mpfootnote #1\relax
    \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfootnote}%
  \endgroup
  \@footnotemark
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section {Symbols}
\label{sec:Symbols}
These macros simply generated predefined symbols in an appropriate font. Change
style.

\bottomcaption{Symbols}
\tablefirsthead%
{
  \hline
  Macro & Definition & Meaning \\
  \hline
%  & & \\
%  \hline
}

\tablehead%
{
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\small\sl continued from previous page} \\
  \hline
  Macro & Definition & Meaning \\
  \hline
%  & & \\
%  \hline
}

\tabletail%
{
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\small\sl continued on next page} \\
  \hline
}

\tablelasttail%
{
  \hline
}

\begin{mpsupertabular}[t]{| l | l | p{3.2in} |}
A & B &  C
\footnote{footnote.}
\newcounter{fn:sub}
\setcounter{fn:sub} {\value{mpfootnote}}
\\
\hline
D & E & F
({\textbackslash}alph\{fn:sub\} = \alph{fn:sub})
\mpfootnotemark[\value{fn:sub}]
\\
\end{mpsupertabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: +1 -- and my heartiest congratulations on achieving the 200k rep mark!!!

Comment: @Mico Thanks, your vote hit the mark exactly!